# How to implement GetEnumerator() and Dispose()?

Tags: c#

I have the following wrapper class for the `IAsyncCursor`

```
public sealed class DeferredResultCollection<TResult> : IEnumerable<TResult>, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IAsyncCursor<TResult> _asyncCursor;

    public DeferredResultCollection(IAsyncCursor<TResult> asyncCursor)
    {
        _asyncCursor = asyncCursor;
    }

    public IEnumerator<TResult> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (; _asyncCursor.MoveNextAsync().Result;)
        {
            foreach (var result in _asyncCursor.Current)
            {
                yield return result;
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_asyncCursor != null)
        {
            _asyncCursor.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new in C# and I would like to add new constructor `IList<TResult>` and implement new methods `GetEnumerator()` and `Dispose()` for the `IList<TResult>`. How to do this? Please, help me.

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand correctly, you'd like to either pull values from the `IAsyncCursor<T>` or the `IList<T>`.

That's pretty simple: Have two fields, and use the one which isn't `null`.

```
public sealed class DeferredResultCollection<TResult> : IEnumerable<TResult>, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IAsyncCursor<TResult> _asyncCursor;
    private readonly ICollection<TResult> _results;

    public DeferredResultCollection(IAsyncCursor<TResult> asyncCursor)
    {
        if (asyncCursor == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(asyncCursor));

        _asyncCursor = asyncCursor;
    }

    public DeferredResultCollection(ICollection<TResult> results)
    {
        if (results == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(results));

        _results = results;
    }

    public IEnumerator<TResult> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _results != null
            ? _results.GetEnumerator()
            : GetAsyncCursorEnumerator();
    }

    private IEnumerator<TResult> GetAsyncCursorEnumerator()
    {
        for (; _asyncCursor.MoveNextAsync().Result;)
        {
            foreach (var result in _asyncCursor.Current)
            {
                yield return result;
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_asyncCursor != null)
        {
            _asyncCursor.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, I would start with adding a second private field:

```
 private readonly IAsyncCursor<TResult> _asyncCursor;
 private readonly IList<TResult> _list;
```

and constructor:

```
public DeferredResultCollection(IList<TResult> list)
{
    _list = list;
}
```

and just checking for which one was populated in your `GetEnumerator`:

```
public IEnumerator<TResult> GetEnumerator()
{
    if(_list) != null
        foreach(var item in _list)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    if(_asyncCursor) != null
        for (; _asyncCursor.MoveNextAsync().Result;)
        {
            foreach (var result in _asyncCursor.Current)
            {
                yield return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

If that works, then you can look to refactor the code and see what (if anything) could be combined or moved to separate methods.

Note that you can't `Dispose` an `IList` because it does not extend `IDisposable` so there's nothing to change in the `Dispose` method.